# Running two Expo Release Channels on the same device?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a testing and production release channel, on TestFlight and the App Store, respectively. I want the ability to run both on the same device. Otherwise if there is an issue with my testing release channel me and my beta users are blocked from using the working production channel (as least without constantly downloading and overwriting the TestFlight vs App Store versions)

I tried https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5, but it seems like most of the configurations were reverted on build, and I wound up with the same bundleIdentifier and therefore I could not download the TestFlight testing version without removing the App Store version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to release multiple apps from 1 source code. We ran into this problem as well and ended up releasing separate test (internal testing), beta (external testing) and production apps. Each with their own app logo, app name and expo release channel. As far as I know, there is no way to switch release channel after your app has been built.

Alternatively you could (beta) test your app by pointing your users to https://exp.host/@username/yourApp?release-channel=. This way your testers can test most of your app’s functionally in the Expo Go app.

You can use [iOS Build Configurations and Android Build Variants](https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5) to easily create different apps within one project.